# Why does Magento show the configurable products and its associated simple products as well?

Tags: magento, search, product, configurable

On my online store, we sell jeans. The configurable products are the different types of jeans, and the associated simple products are the sizes for each (6,8,10,12,14). When i search for a product or just scroll on the feed it doesnt only show the configurable products and when i click it you can choose the size, but the individual simple products show up too eg:
Skinny Jeans
Skinny Jeans-6
Skinny Jeans-8 etc. How do i fix this?

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the root of the problem... :/ any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For your simple products, you can set its `Visibility`. You can change it under

```
Product Information > General > Visibility > Not Visible Individually
```

This way they won't appear on front-end while still being associated with your `configurable` product.